# Url Pattern not matching in Routers | Django Restframewok

Tags: python, django, django-3.1

I have configured a viewset inheriting **viewsets.ModelViewSet** in views.py. And updated the **urls.py** to use Routers as follows

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets/<int:id>', SnippetViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),   
]
```

But when accessing this URL pattern it says there is no matching pattern and results in page not found.

NB: Django version : 3.1, djangorestframework version 3.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the url pattern in router.register should be like this

```
router.register(r'snippets/(?P<id>[0-9]+)', SnippetViewSet)
```